# Explode map type column that has another map type inside in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My dataset schema looks like this

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col3: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- col4: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: integer
 |    |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
```

`col4` is a map type, however, inside it, there's another map.

I can use `explode(col4)` to get

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col3: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |-- value: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
```

How am I supposed to explode the `value` column now?

A stupid way would be renaming the `key` column, and explode the `value` column again... but I'm trying to do it in a nice way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `udf` function to flatten the *Map* `col4` column as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def flatNestedMap = udf((maps: Map[String,Map[Int, Long]])=> maps.flatMap(x => x._2.map(y => (x._1, y._1, y._2))).toArray)
```

Then you can just use one `explode` on the column returned by `udf` function and then `select` the necessary columns

```
df.withColumn("col4", explode(flatNestedMap(col("col4"))))
    .select(col("col1"), col("col2"), col("col3"), col("col4._1").as("outerKey"), col("col4._2").as("innerKey"), col("col4._3").as("innerValue"))
```

Thats it. I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks!  It's so helpful